# Calling procedure inside procedure manipulate returned results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures - test_proc and calling_proc. Procedure test_proc is being called inside procedure calling_proc.

Result looks like this:

[image]

Is is possible to have only one row returned from calling_proc (instead of four rows), which will look like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| test1 | test2 | test3 | test4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |     3 |     4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Procedures:

```
create procedure test_proc
as
begin
select 1 test1
select 2 test2
select 3 test3
end

create procedure calling_proc
as
begin
exec test_proc
select 4 test4
end
```

Comment: Replace the last 2 selects with commas in the first proc. Then you'll have to store the results of exec test proc into a temp table and join to it in the final proc

Comment: Can you show me example, please. I don't know how to store results from stored procedure call into temp table..

Comment: Each select statement will give you a result set. So if you want multiple columns in a select statement, separate them by commas. This is really basic sql. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql

Comment: I completely understand this, this is the easy part. What I don't know is how to store results [test1, test2, test3] from test_proc to temp table and combine those results with [test4] column.

Comment: It is not clear what you are describing based on the data you provided. Do you actually want a temp table? Or just a row with the 4 results?

Comment: I need a row with 4 results.

Comment: Are you using a stored procedure for any reason specifically? You have no inputs.

Comment: My production stored procedure is much larger and much more complicated. Problem is that it calls another procedure, but my framework works only on one row of returned data. That is why I would like to combine results into one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...depending on your environment you'll have to change the server settings. But use `OPENROWSET`

```
SELECT * 
INTO #MyTempTable 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC test_proc')

SELECT *, 4 AS test4 
FROM #MyTempTable
```

Or, something like this...

```
CREATE #MyTempTable (test1 int, test2 int, test3 int, test4 int)
INSERT INTO #MyTemptTable (test1,test2,test3)
EXEC test_proc

UPDATE #MyTempTable
SET test4 = 4
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a homework assignment and they are just looking for a select statement and the teacher is going to look at this and know it wasn't done by a beginner. :) But you *did* answer the question, so have an upvote!

Comment: @JacobH - please go and comment somewhere else.

Comment: What? Did I hit a nerve? You barely made any effort at all and didn't do any research and you want someone to write your code for you.